# TypeScript Generic Parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to make my log method to be generic. What I need as the main concept is as below:

```
class A {
    user_id: number;
    // and some other props...
}

class B {
    service_name: string;
    // and some other props...
}

function log<T>(...T parameters) {
    // logging the input parameters
}

log<A>(
    A.user_id = 123
);

log<B>(
    B.service_name = 'my_service_name';
);
```

What I have tried so far is as below, but I cannot make it working. I am doing this, because my project is getting bigger and more levels and entries would be added day-to-day.

```
enum levels {
    error,
    info,
}

enum entries {
    user_id,
    service_name,
}

function log(level: levels, ...entries: entries[]) {
    // perform the actual log...
}

log(
    levels.info,
    entries.user_id = 123
);

log(
    levels.error,
    entries.service_name = 'my_sevice_name'    
);
```

The reason that I have used enums in my example, is that I wanted to force the developer to choose a predefined value from a list and not to use magic numbers or magic strings.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve...I don't understand the use of enums in the seconds codeblock

Comment: I will edit my question now, to be more clear.

Comment: try changing the enums to interface or a plain object literal.

Comment: Ok so what you want to do is limit the user's choices to fixed values for the parameters

Answer (score 2):

Is it as simple as using unions to define the keys?

```
type Level = "error" | "info"

type EntryKey = "user_id" | "service_name"

type Entry = Partial<{
  [K in EntryKey]:string
}>

function log(level: Level, ...entries: Entry[]) {
    // perform the actual log...
}

log("error", {service_name:"something"})
```

Comment: Ah! This was more what I was talking about earlier, List of types or `unions`

Answer (score 1):

If you want your second solution to "work" you'd have to change the function calls to this:

```js
enum levels {
    error,
    info,
}

interface entry {
    user_id,
    service_name,
}

function log(level: levels, ...entries: entry[]) {
    // perform the actual log...
}

log(
    levels.info,
    { user_id: 123 }
);

log(
    levels.error,
    { service_name: 'my_sevice_name' }
);
```

Comment: I do not want the developer to freely type keys in the object. I want to provide a list for developer to choose from.

Comment: Can you please post an example in your question

Comment: Then you are not wanting to use Generics

Comment: Give them a list of inputs 
input | input2 | input3 etc...

Comment: I don't want to have several inputs, because the entries will be a lot and there would be a lot number of inputs then.

Comment: @MrCodingB, the second code snippet is my example.

Comment: I updated my answer according to your second snippet

Comment: In this case, the developer is not able to choose the entries from a list. I want the developer to choose the entries from a list.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking of something like this then
`entries: keyof typeof entry`
that works with `enum` and might work `interface`